# Rows not saving update in EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 3000 parents I need to mass update. First I thought I would use SQL server to do the mass update and feed it an array, but the array proved too long and I got errors that the string I was feeding for the `WHERE IN ()` clause would be truncated.

So I went back to EF, but whatever I do, the changes are not saved.
When I inspect the locals, I see the changes in the objects, but when `db.SaveChages()` is done, the changes are not in the database.

I am clueless here.

```
    public void UpdateParentStatus(List<int> primaryParentIds)
    {
        //string queryArray = string.Join(",", primaryParentIds);
        //db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE Parent SET IsPrimary = 1 WHERE ParentId IN ({0})", queryArray);
        foreach (int id in primaryParentIds)
        {
            var parentResult = pList.Single(p => p.ParentId == id);
            parentResult.IsPrimary = true;
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is `pList` and how are you setting that variable/field/property?

Comment: Which has a `public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }`

Comment: The interessting part is where are the contents of pList comin from. You have a context named 'db' but your objects seem to come from somewhere else

Comment: As others have said would be nice to see where plist is coming from.  You might be able to add db.Entry(parent).State = EntityState.Modified;  After you set IsPrimary to to true.  I'm assuming your issue may be a disconnected model but without more code no way to know.

Comment: That did the trick :) So stupid, totally overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (int id in primaryParentIds)
{
    var parentResult = pList.Single(p => p.ParentId == id);
    parentResult.IsPrimary = true;
    pList.Entry(parentResult).EntityState = EntityState.Modified;
}
db.SaveChanges();
```